# How to find the Total Number of Requests processed by tomcat server?

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I want to host a tomcat server, which will host 3 web applications. I want to get the total number of requests processed by my server(for any of the 3 web applications). Is there any log  from where I can check the total number of requests processed by my server(including HTTP 404 requests)

**Note : I can calculate the total requests processed by each individual application and get the total number of requests processed by my server, but the applications deployed in tomcat are third-party and i cant do any changes in it.**

Basically, I am building a monitoring application for the tomcat server and I have to provide the total requests served in the application,

Also, My first thought was to over-ride the HTTPServletRequest class constructor in servlet-api.jar and put a static counter. since every request is mapped to HTTPServletRequest object, I guess it will do the job. But is it a good idea to over-ride the HTTPServletRequest or is there any existing solution available for this?

Comment: You could write a very simple [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), but it would have to be added to each context and results would be counted independently, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do choose to override the HTTPServletRequest class do not just add a static counter, this will cause your counter to reset itself each time the Server goes down/jvm reloads.

I think it might be a better option to either increment it from a database or save the value in a file each time. This way you do not loose your count even if something happens to the server and you have to restart it.

This is all assuming that there isn't already a Apache extension that already dose this and you do want to tinker with the HTTPServletRequest class.

Comment: assuming there isnt't already any apache extension, your answer is superb..+1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special filter called [Request Dumper Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) for this purpose.

According to official Tomcat Documentation:

```
The following entries in a web application's web.xml would enable the Request Dumper 
filter for all requests for that web application. If the entries were added to 
CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml, the Request Dumper Filter would be enabled for all web 
applications.
```